# next.js link object nog showing when passing in href in contentmanagement system

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, next.js

I have to build a blog with next.js, and now I want to display some hyperlinks in the blog via the content management system using rich text.

As seen in the image, the data objects paragraph is showing in the blog and the link (`href` link) is nog showing.

[data objects href not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8peG9.png)

The code looks like this:

```
const PostDetail = ( { post }) => {

const getContentFragment = (index, text, obj, type) => {
    let modifiedText = text;
        
    if (obj) {
        if (obj.bold) {
            modifiedText = (<b key={index}>{text}</b>);
        }
    
        if (obj.italic) {
            modifiedText = (<em key={index}>{text}</em>);
        }
    
        if (obj.underline) {
            modifiedText = (<u key={index}>{text}</u>);
        }
              
    }
    
    switch (type) {
        case 'heading-one':
            return <h1 key={index} className="text-3xl font-semibold mb-4">{modifiedText.map((item, i) => <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>)}</h1>;
        case 'heading-three':
        case 'heading-two':
            return <h2 key={index} className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">{modifiedText.map((item, i) => <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>)}</h2>;
        case 'heading-three':
            return <h3 key={index} className="text-xl font-semibold mb-4">{modifiedText.map((item, i) => <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>)}</h3>;
        case 'paragraph':
            return <p key={index} className="mb-8">{modifiedText.map((item, i) => <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>)}</p>;
        case 'heading-four':
            return <h4 key={index} className="text-md font-semibold mb-4">{modifiedText.map((item, i) => <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>)}</h4>;
        case 'link':
            return <Link key={index} href={href} className="text-md font-semibold mb-4">{modifiedText.map((item, i) => <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>)}</Link>;
        case 'script':
            return <script key={index} className="text-md font-semibold mb-4">{modifiedText.map((item, i) => <React.Fragment key={i}>{item}</React.Fragment>)}</script>;
                
        case 'image':
            return (
              <img
                key={index}
                alt={obj.title}
                height={obj.height}
                width={obj.width}
                src={obj.src}
              />
            );
        default:
            return modifiedText;
            
        }
    };

    return (
      <>
      <div className="bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg lg:p-8 pb-12 mb-8">
        <div className="relative overflow-hidden shadow-md mb-6">
          <img src={post.featuredImage.url} alt="" className="object-top h-full w-full object-cover  shadow-lg rounded-t-lg lg:rounded-lg" />
        </div>
        <div className="px-4 lg:px-0">
          <div className="flex items-center mb-8 w-full">
            <div className="hidden md:flex items-center justify-center lg:mb-0 lg:w-auto mr-8 items-center">
              <img
                alt={post.author.name}
                height="30px"
                width="30px"
                className="align-middle rounded-full"
                src={post.author.photo.url}
              />
              <p className="inline align-middle text-gray-700 ml-2 font-medium text-lg">{post.author.name}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="font-medium text-gray-700">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6 inline mr-2 text-pink-500" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z" />
              </svg>
              <span className="align-middle">{moment(post.createdAt).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h1 className="mb-8 text-3xl font-semibold">{post.title}</h1>
          {post.content.raw.children.map((typeObj, index) => {
            const children = typeObj.children.map((item, itemindex) => getContentFragment(itemindex, item.text, item));
            
            console.log(post.content.raw)

            return getContentFragment(index, children, typeObj, typeObj.type);
          })}
        </div>
      </div>

    </>
    )
 }

export default PostDetail
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this is from JavaScript Mastery blog tutorial. I had the exact same problem.

Ended up changing PostDetail.jsx to this:

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import { RichText } from "@graphcms/rich-text-react-renderer";

const PostDetail = ({ post }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg lg:p-8 pb-12 mb-8">
        <div className="relative overflow-hidden shadow-md mb-6">
          <img
            src={post.featuredImage.url}
            alt=""
            className="object-top h-full w-full object-cover  shadow-lg rounded-t-lg lg:rounded-lg"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="px-4 lg:px-0">
          <div className="flex items-center mb-8 w-full">
            <div className="hidden md:flex items-center justify-center lg:mb-0 lg:w-auto mr-8 items-center">
              <img
                alt={post.author.name}
                height="30px"
                width="30px"
                className="align-middle rounded-full"
                src={post.author.photo.url}
              />
              <p className="inline align-middle text-gray-700 ml-2 font-medium text-lg">
                {post.author.name}
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="font-medium text-gray-700">
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                className="h-6 w-6 inline mr-2 text-pink-500"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth="2"
                  d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z"
                />
              </svg>
              <span className="align-middle">
                {moment(post.createdAt).format("MMM DD, YYYY")}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h1 className="mb-8 text-3xl font-semibold">{post.title}</h1>

          <div className="mb-8">
            {post.excerpt && (
              <p
                className="text-gray-700 text-center text-lg
              font-normal px-4 lg:px-20 mb-8"
              ></p>
            )}
            <RichText content={post.content.raw.children} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PostDetail;
```

You might run into a problem in Hygraph, where you can't put extra line breaks in your posts. Simply press shift + enter (instead of just enter).